# How to get sorted result within INNER JOIN on joined table

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to get results from a join of 2 tables. Typically, not an issue, but I'm banging my head on this one. Basically, table1 (sales_dealers) is joined with table2 (sales_dealerEvents). Normally, easy-peasy. The problem is that I want to only get records from table2 if there are only 2 events (why I added the HAVING). But I need to get the value of the second event. With my query now, I can only get the value of the first event. It's like I need an ORDER BY EventID DESC on the joined table. It giving me ASC by default with this query.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT e.EventAction
     , d.DealerID
     , d.AgentID
     , d.DealerName
     , d.Email
     , SUBSTRING_INDEX(d.PrimaryContactName, ' ', 1) AS FirstName
     , d.State
     , COUNT(e.EventID) AS EventCount
  FROM sales_dealers d
  JOIN sales_dealerEvents e
    ON d.DealerID = e.DealerID
 WHERE d.AgentID = 1
   AND d.StatusID = 3
   AND d.Email REGEXP '^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9._-]*@[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9._-]*\\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$'
 GROUP 
    BY d.DealerID
HAVING COUNT(e.EventID) = 2
 ORDER 
    BY e.EventID DESC
```

Here is my Schema for the two tables (mysql version 5.7.27 )

```
sales_dealers
------------------
DealerID (int PK)
StatusID (int)
AgentID (int)
DealerName (varchar)
Email (varchar)
PrimaryContactName (varchar)
State (varchar)

sales_dealerEvents
------------------
EventID (int PK)
DealerID (FK)
AgentID (FK)
EventDateTime (datetime)
EventAction (longtext)
```

Here is sample data. Currently, the above query returns this:

```
Prospect Entry  784     1   Dealer Name One     sales@dealer.com            CA  2
Prospect Entry  782     1   Some other dealer   hello@dealer.com            MT  2
Prospect Entry  781     1   Dealer Store        contact@dealer.com          OK  2
```

I would like it to return this:

```
Initial Contact 784     1   Dealer One      sales@dealer.com            CA  2
Initial Contact 782     1   Some other dealer   hello@dealer.com            MT  2
Initial Contact 781     1   Dealer Store        contact@dealer.com          OK  2
```

Here is the same sample data of but showing the relationship of the one to many in sales_dealerEvents

```
sales_dealer
    784 Dealer Name One

sales_dealerEvents
    1000    784 1 Prospect Entry    2020-06-02 01:00:00
    1010    784 1 Initial Contact   2020-07-03 01:00:00
```

I'm feeling I might have to do this in a subquery to sort the event so the second event is first. Not sure. I might also need to match criteria of that second event too.

**UPDATE - Here is my SQL fiddle**
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ef6f2c/2

As you can see with the fiddle.. all event records returned are 'prospect entry'.. which were the first entries for 'events' for those. Each have 2. The second is 'Initial Contact'. Their date and EventID is after the 'prospect entry'.

Comment: Please define "second" event.  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets, so this concept is not clear.

Comment: @GordonLinoff In this case, all the records returning are 2 events per dealer. That's good, but 'Prospect Entry' is what comes up first in every case. Which is the first event. I want the 2nd event out of the two which is 'Initial Contact'. You can see that in the sample data above.

Comment: @Strawberry - Just added SQL fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope the below query helps and you can see the demo here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ef6f2c/37/0

```
SELECT
   EventAction,
   DealerID,
   AgentID,
   DealerName,
   Email,
   FirstName,
   State,
   EventID 
from
   (
      SELECT
         e.EventAction,
         d.DealerID,
         d.AgentID,
         d.DealerName,
         d.Email,
         SUBSTRING_INDEX(d.PrimaryContactName, ' ', 1) AS FirstName,
         d.State,
         e.EventID as EventID 
      FROM
         sales_dealers d 
         JOIN
            sales_dealerEvents e 
            ON d.DealerID = e.DealerID 
      WHERE
         d.AgentID = 1 
         AND d.StatusID = 3 
         AND d.Email REGEXP '^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9._-]*@[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9._-]*\\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$' 
      ORDER BY
         e.EventID DESC 
   )
   a 
GROUP BY
   DealerID 
HAVING
   COUNT(EventID) = 2
```

Comment: The fiddle works, but for some reason it does not work on my mysql server? I created a test database and took the schema from fiddle and executed the query. Prospect Entry was displayed for all 3 records on my server. This is what I'm running - mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.27

Comment: @hanji, MySQL version doesn't matter here. But it's strange that it returns different results. Can you try `ORDER BY e.EventID ASC` in your query and let me know the results?

Comment: I did try that.. and also ORDER BY EventDateTime DESC/ASC and the same result returns. Again, this is based on the schema in the fiddle on test database. They should match. Very odd.

Comment: @hanji, I don't know is there any synonyms created for these tables. Can you try changing the table names and see the results?

Comment: Looks like version does matter. I tested on two 5.7.27 servers... didn't work. I tried on a server that has 8.0.20.. didn't work. But I found a server with 5.6.40.. and it worked? That fiddle is 5.6

Comment: 5.6 to 5.7 deprecations - this one seems interesting: GROUP BY implicitly sorts by default (that is, in the absence of ASC or DESC designators), but relying on implicit GROUP BY sorting in MySQL 5.7 is deprecated. To achieve a specific sort order of grouped results, it is preferable to use To produce a given sort order, use explicit ASC or DESC designators for GROUP BY columns or provide an ORDER BY clause....

Comment: continued...
GROUP BY sorting is a MySQL extension that may change in a future release; for example, to make it possible for the optimizer to order groupings in whatever manner it deems most efficient and to avoid the sorting overhead.

Comment: @hanji, thank you for the knowledge share. Then did you try explicit SORT ORDER to see if that works?

Comment: Yes! I got this to work now. I changed ORDER BY e.EventID DESC to GROUP BY e.EventID DESC

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like you want window functions:

```
select . . .
from sales_dealers d join
     (select e.*,
             row_number() over (partition by e.DealerID order by e.EventDateTime) as seqnum
      from sales_dealerEvents e
     ) e
     on e.DealerID = d.DealerID and e.seqnum = 2
where . . .
```

Note this gets data from the *second* event even if there are more than two events.  That seems consistent with the question, but it is easy enough to use `count(*)` as a window function to do further filtering.

Comment: This is interesting. Not familiar with partition. I get the following error:

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(partition by e.DealerID order by e.EventDateTime) as seqnum
      from sales_d' at line 5

Comment: @hanji . . . Window functions were introduced in MySQL 8+ (in 2018).  Older versions don't support it.